# ml-gradle local message error causing deployment to fail

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I am trying to use ml-Gradle to deploy my application to a MarkLogic Server on an EC2 instance in AWS. I am getting the following error for any gradle command I run and I can't find any information about it on the web.

Error:
`Error occurred while loading REST modules: Error occurred while loading modules; host: <IP IS HERE BUT TAKEN OUT BY ME FOR THIS POST>; port: 8010; cause: Local message: /config/query not found for write. Server Message: Request failed. Error body not received from server`

I know that I am hitting the correct ip address for the host and have the proper credentials. Has anyone seen this before? This deploys fine in our DEV environment, so it is strange it is not working in this environment.

Comment: Are you sure 8010 is visible from outside? If you are deploying through an SSH tunnel, you will need to distinguish between the port that is used from gradle side, and the port used to configure MarkLogic.

Comment: Try hitting host:8010/v1/config/query via your web browser to see if that resolves. Also check to see if an SSL connection is required.

Comment: @rjrudin Interesting finding. In our DEV environment where the deployment is working I get the following output from running a curl request against host:8010/v1/config/query:
`<rapi:query-options xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
  <rapi:options>
    <rapi:name>default</rapi:name>
    <rapi:uri>/v1/config/query/default</rapi:uri>
  </rapi:options>
  <rapi:options>
    <rapi:name>staging-entity-options</rapi:name>
    <rapi:uri>/v1/config/query/staging-entity-options</rapi:uri>
  </rapi:options>
</rapi:query-options>`

I get nothing back in the environment its failing in.

Comment: @rjrudin I looked into the modules database and found both files. They match exactly what is in our DEV environment, but the curl request brings back nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the url rewriter on the 8010 App-Server had a strange value. It ended up containing %%mlVersion%% and not a normal url. Once I updated the url rewriter in the App Server settings to match what we had in DEV and PROD everything worked as expected. I do not know how this url rewriter value was set to a different value in the first place.